# Get the closed form of Taylor series with Maple

Tags: power-series, maple

Is it possible to get the closed form of Taylor series with Maple?

The `series` command can give any given number of terms, but the question is about the closed form of the *entire* Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

Try **convert(expression, FPS, variable)** or **convert(expression, FPS, variable = a)**, e.g.

```
convert(exp(x), FPS, x);
```

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^k}{k!} $$

Of course it won't always work, but for many functions that have reasonably simple Taylor (or Laurent) series it will.

EDIT: This **might** sometimes work for a bivariate series as well.  Maybe not in your case, but in the simpler case of $(1 - a x - b y)^{-1}$:

```
convert((1-a*x-b*y)^(-1), FPS, x);
convert(%, FPS, y);
```

$$ \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left( \sum _{{\it k1}=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{a}^{
k}{x}^{k}{b}^{{\it k1}}{\it pochhammer} \left( k+1,{\it k1} \right) {y
}^{{\it k1}}}{{\it k1}!}} \right) 
$$

Comment: thank you
but it didn't work. sorry my question was no accurate. I need closed form of taylor (Maclaurin) series of 2-variables function.
realy I need it for this function:
f(X,Y)= (1- aX - bY - cXY)^(-1)

Comment: It sometimes helps if you ask the question that you really want answered.  I don't know if the bivariate Maclaurin series of that function has a closed form.